# Is NaN always a falsy value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, nan, type-coercion, falsy

```js
console.log(typeof 3/0, Boolean(3/0)); // This returns NaN true
console.log(typeof 0/0, Boolean(0/0)); // This returns NaN false
```

I thought both will return `NaN` false in the Console as `NaN` is *falsy* value. But this is not happening. Can someone please explain this.

I used VS Code editor and Google Chrome Browser.

Comment: Try `typeof (3/0)`, as `3/0` actually gives `Infinity`, so the type is "number" (you're actually doing `(typeof 3)/0`)

Comment: Ref: [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: Got it!  Thanks ... and thanks for editing the question also.

Answer (score 1):

The result of `3/0` is `Infinity` (which is not `NaN`).

Infinity is a thruty value by spec.